# Cannot download latest library from nuget

Tags: .net, vb.net, nuget, codeplex, hashlib

I am trying to install [HashLib](https://hashlib.codeplex.com/releases) from CodePlex using Nuget Package Manager.

After performing some test, I found out that NuGet install HashLib version 2.01 for me instead of the latest version 2.1 as per CodePlex.

Is there a way to force Nuget to download the latest version?

As HashLib is written in C# and my program is developed using VB.NET, If I were to install directly via Nuget, the library will be automatically installed/converted accordingly hence I am able to develop easily.

However, if I were to download the C# coding directly from CodePlex, I am not sure how do I implement it into my VB.Net project. Understand there are online C# to VB.Net conversion but it is not 100% accurate.

Please advise any steps to ease my development?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package creator apparently didn't bother to package and upload the newer version to NuGet: the [most recent (and only) version is 2.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HashLib/).

You can download and compile the C# project from CodePlex and reference the DLL from your VB.NET project.

Comment: Managed to compile the DLL and add it into my VB project despite facing multiple issues such as .net framework 4.5.1 error, misc output errors on my VS 2012. Thanks for your answer @CodeCaster .